# Forward SMS messages to Google Voice

Tags: sms, forward, google-voice

I have set up forwarding for voice successfully using the twimlet in the Twilio request URL...
http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=000-000-0000

I would like to do the same for SMS messages but get errors if i place this timlet into the SMS request URL

Thank you

Comment: Hey doctor I have pain *somewhere*. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The forward Twimlet is currently designed to work with voice phone calls only.  If you want to forward text messages this is something that you would have to create yourself.

Check out this FAQ article for an example that shows how to forward SMS messages:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-forward-my-sms-messages-to-another-phone-number

Hope that helps.